# Sorting in angular objects in an array alphabetically

Tags: html, angular, typescript, sorting

Suppose your ts code is like this:

```
 items: { size: number, name: string }[] = [];

 ngOnInit(): void {

 this.items = [
      {
        size: 3, name: 'Richard'
      },
      {
        size: 17, name: 'Alex'
      },
      {
        size: 10, name: 'John'
      }]
}
```

How can you sort alphabetically (ascending and descending order) the name property of this array when clicking on a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define two buttons that will pass `asc` or `desc` flag to a function. Execute the function to do the sorting:

html:

```
<button (click)="sort(true)">ASC</button>
<button (click)="sort(false)">DESC</button>
```

component.ts:

```
sort(isAsc: boolean) {
  if (isAsc) {
    this.items.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? 1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? -1 : 0)
  } else {
    this.items.sort((a, b) => (a.name > b.name) ? -1 : ((b.name > a.name) ? 1 : 0)
  }
}
```

ASC:

[image]

Desc:

[image]